# Is it faster to read large amounts of data from multiple .txt files or from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I am working on a personal project (using Python 3) that will retrieve weather information for any city in the United States.  My program prompts the user to enter as many city-state combinations as they wish, and then it retrieves the weather information and creates a weather summary for each city entered.  Behind the scenes, I'm essentially taking the State entered by the user, opening a .txt file corresponding to that State, and then getting a weather code that is associated with the city entered, which I then use in a URL request to find weather information for the city.  Since I have a .txt file for every state, I have 50 .txt files, each with a large number of city-weather code combinations.

Would it be faster to keep my algorithm the way that it currently is, or would it be faster to keep all of this data in a dictionary? This is how I was thinking about storing the data in a dictionary:

```
info = {'Virginia':{'City1':'ID1','City2':'ID2'},'North Carolina':{'City3':'ID3'}}
```

I'd be happy to provide some of my code or elaborate if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: How big are those txt files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large datafile, you will spend days shifting through the file and putting the values in the .py file. If it is a small file I would use a dictionary, but if it were a large file a .txt file.

Other possible solutions are:

- sqlite
- [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)
- [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)

#### Other Resources

[Basic data storage with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276230/basic-data-storage-with-python)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly would be much faster to preload the data from the files, *if* you're using the same python process for many user requests. If the process handles just one request and exits, this approach would be slower *and* use more memory. For some number of requests between "one" and "many", they'd be about equal on speed.

For a situation like this I would probably use [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), for which python has built-in support. It would be much faster than scanning text files without the time and memory overhead of loading the full dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a very good idea to have a large amount of text files, because it will slow down in large or numerous director(y|ies) access. But If you have large data records, you might wish to choose an intermediate solution, in indexing one data file and load the index in a dictionary.